# "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form." - SQL Server VSTS CI-CD deployment

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have been working out VSTS for continuous integration/deployment to an on-premise server.  I have successfully build a dummy set of artifacts in my build from a VSTS Git repository, which include the Customer and Country tables.  I have managed a successful deployment via .dacpac, but am looking to replicate the same with a script-based deployment.

For the build I am publishing all artifacts, my sql files located here:

[image: List of Artifcats]

In the release tasks, I am using the SQL database deployment task. he settings I have used for an .sql rather than .dacpac deployment is as follows:

[image: Development]

[image: SQL Deployment]

[image: Deploy to Dev]

The release fails on the 'Deploy to Dev' task with the following log:

```
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4218768Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy to Dev
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4233677Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4233951Z Task         : SQL Server Database Deploy
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4234238Z Description  : Deploy to SQL Server Database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4234458Z Version      : 0.3.10
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4234642Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4234859Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/sqldacpacmachinegroupreadme)
2018-05-31T08:14:21.4235150Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-31T08:14:24.2246881Z ##[error]Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."
2018-05-31T08:14:24.2348684Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy to Dev
```

I had thought that using the `**/*.sql` wildcard would have meant that it would cycle through all the SQL files and execute.  I also tried the same by jsut asking it to execute the customer file (`**/Customer.sql`) and received the same error.

I was hoping someone could review my config and identify where my understanding is falling short?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have SSDT generate a SQL script and then run it, if you want to run a SQL script. The approach you're trying to implement will not work. You can't just run through a list of SQL scripts in alphabetical order and expect that the schema will be updated correctly; schema changes frequently have requirements on the order in which they're run.

Comment: Can you share the detail log here or on the OneDrive? (Add system.debug variable and set it to true, then start release) Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share the sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: @DanielMann The OP's right. I use the DacPac option ok, then try to run some post deployment scripts that are named numerically with the wildcard, and I get the same issue. The docs are misleading: `Wildcards can be used. For example, **/*.sql for sql file present in all sub folders`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried to put in the working directory variable and it worked. For example $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.sql

Comment: I was able to resolve the path by adding a directory name, but still facing issue "No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.sql"  the SQL file is not executing, any additional steps need to have to run the script?